# How can I find a linear transformation $\mathcal{T}$ that maps an ellipse to a circle?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, education

Let $\mathcal{T}(x,y)=(x',y')$ be a linear transformation.

The image of the ellipse $4x^2-4\sqrt{2}xy+11y^2=12$ under the transformation $\mathcal{T}$ is the circle $x'^2+y'^2=4$.

Comment: You could combine a rotation and stretch matrix according.

Comment: [How to ask a homework question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question)

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard way to do this kind of exercise; you have to "complete the squares":
\begin{gather}
4x^2-4\sqrt 2 xy+ 11y^2 = 12\\
\left(2x-\sqrt 2 y\right)^2 -2y^2 + 11y^2 = 12\\
\left(2x-\sqrt 2 y\right)^2 + \left(3y\right)^2 = 12\\
\left(\frac{2x-\sqrt 2 y}{\sqrt 3}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{3y}{\sqrt 3}\right)^2 = 4\\
\end{gather}

So if a point $P=(\bar x,\bar y)$ lies in the ellipse $4x^2-4\sqrt 2 xy +11y^2 = 12$, then the point $Q=\left(\frac{2\bar x-\sqrt 2 \bar y}{\sqrt 3},\frac{3 \bar y}{\sqrt 3}\right)$ lies in the ellipse $x^2+y^2 = 4$.

Thanks to the above remark, the linear map you are looking for is:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal T (x,y) = \left(\frac{2 x-\sqrt 2 y}{\sqrt 3},\frac{3 y}{\sqrt 3}\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: In the second equality, shouldn't $(2x-2\sqrt 2 y)^2$ be replaced by $(2x-\sqrt 2 y)^2$?

Comment: @Pedro Yes, you're right! Thanks

Comment: I might note that this solution isn’t unique: composing $\mathcal T$ with an abitrary rotation or reflection also results in the ellipse being mapped to the unit circle.